# Как правильно вызвать класс нового окна графического интерфейса?

Tags: python, классы, tkinter

При запуске программы всплывает сразу два окна. Графический интерфейс - tkinter.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второе окно должно появляться при нажатии на кнопку добавить.

Вот часть кода:
Первый файл:

```
class TransportApp:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title('Грузовой транспорт')
        master.geometry('780x280')

        # Создание графического интерфейса
        self.create_widgets()

    # Главная страница
    def create_widgets(self):
        create_label(self.master, "ГЛАВНОЕ МЕНЮ", 1, 1, 2)

        create_button(self.master, "Добавить грузовой транспорт", 2, 1, AddWindow().add_win)
```

......Попытка вызвать класс - последняя строка выше.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = TransportApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Второй файл:

```
class AddWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.add_window = Tk()
        self.add_window.title("Добавить грузовой транспорт")
        self.add_window.geometry("400x300")

    def add_win(self):
        create_label(self.add_window, "Название", 1, 1)
        self.ent1 = create_entry(self.add_window, 1, 2)
        create_label(self.add_window, "Грузоподъемность, тонн", 2, 1)
        self.ent2 = create_entry(self.add_window, 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

В основном окне создайте метод добавление нового окна, тогда он будет вызываться после нажатия кнопки, а не во время её создания.

```
import tkinter as tk


class AddWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.title("Добавить грузовой транспорт")
        self.geometry("400x300")


class TransportApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Грузовой транспорт')
        self.geometry('780x280')

        # Создание графического интерфейса
        self.create_widgets()

    # Главная страница
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.create_button = tk.Button(self.master, text="Добавить грузовой транспорт", command=self.add_window)
        self.create_button.pack()

    def add_window(self):
        window = AddWindow(self)
        window.grab_set()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = TransportApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

[Как создавать дополнительные окна в tkinter](https://pythonru.com/uroki/vsplyvajushhie-okna-tkinter-11)